# How to test if database records are ordered by id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, testing

I'm testing a JSON API. And up until recently I assumed the records are returned ordered by id. But when `Posts.all` turned into `Posts.where(user_id: params[:user_id])`, it broke the following test:

```
it 'takes "limit" param' do
  post1 = create :post
  post2 = create :post, user_id: post1.user_id
  get user_posts_path(post1.user_id, limit: 1)
  expect(response.body).to be_json_eql([{id: post1.id}].to_json).including(only: :id)
end
```

I can probably add the following test:

```
it 'returns records ordered by id' do
  post1 = create :post
  post2 = create :post, user_id: post1.user_id
  get user_posts_path(post1.user_id)
  expect(response.body).to be_json_eql([{id: post1.id}, {id: post2.id}].to_json).including(only: :id)
end
```

but it succeeds without adding `.order(:id)` to the controller. I'd like to make sure it's there. What do I do?

Comment: I think your test should verify behavior, not how it was coded. The question becomes, how can you eliminate false positives?

Comment: Sure, I don't care what's in the controller, I want to ensure that results are ordered by id, always, not generally.

Answer (score 1):

The order is not guaranteed, so while you might get the behaviour of the results being ordered by id, it's not guaranteed, and you should not rely on it.

See "[Why is SSMS inserting new rows at the top of a table not the bottom?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/why-is-ssms-inserting-new-rows-at-the-top-of-a-table-not-the-bottom/5775#5775)"

Also, as it mostly returns by id, your test will mostly succeed without the order set but it tells you nothing and is bad practice.

So, are you really asking if I do something that's not safe, how can I write a test to check if something bad happens as result?

I'm not sure why you would do that. You've got a potential intermittent bug that will appear when the database decides it wants to, on any environment. Even if it doesn't happen in your testing environment it may happen in production, so it tells you nothing. Remove the bug by adding an order, then your test should pass through a known behaviour.

Comment: I'd like to have a test that ensures, that there is `.order(:id)` in controller. Because if there's no such test, `.order(:id)` might go one day and the test suit won't fail. Or I'll got failures in random places, testing other things. In other words, I don't want to do the unsafe thing. I want to ensure that I'm doing the safe thing.